# How to disable IOS double-tap zoom in mobile browser for a Angular webapp? (I tried everything)

Tags: html, css, ios, angular, google-chrome

I tried :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0"/>


<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

and

```
body {
  touch-action: manipulation !important;
}
```

and nothing worked, I still have the double tap on safari and chrome on iOS.

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

CSS to disable double-tap zoom globally:

```
* {
  touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

Edit:

I tested it with this on a IPhone 7 Plus with IOS v14.4.2 and it works for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>No double tap</title>
  <style>
    .no-double-tap {
      touch-action: manipulation;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>no double tap</h2>
  <img class="no-double-tap" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300">
  <h2>double tap</h2>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added an example which works on my device.

Answer (score 0):

```
# This code more helped me in my angular app!!!
```

```css
body{
    touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0"/>
```